# Uploading a file crashes Desktop App Web Viewer

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, appsource

We are facing problems while uploading files via our o365 addin on Windows. In the compose mode, we launch a iframed app via a ribbon button. This iframed app which launches in a Desktop App Web Viewer allows users to upload files. The problem is that as soon as the users are done selecting the files they want to upload, the Desktop App Web Viewer crashes and we are back to the compose view. This happens intermittently but is frequent enough to be problematic.

I looked at some Office JS issues and came across [this](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1069) one but wasn't sure if this is related. I also looked at some Outlook logs but couldn't find anything useful. The error logs didn't say anything much beyond the code - 15003. There were some other informational logs around the timeline of the crashes, but I can't say for sure if those are related. One was related to [Software Protection Service](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/298c11d5-02ec-4627-9916-7182d994be3b/successfully-scheduled-software-protection-service-for-restart-reason-rulesengine?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows) and the other one hinted at [memory leaks](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1322989).

If I use the app to upload files outside of the Office environment, the app never crashes (both in Edge and IE11).

Any insights on this issue?

Comment: a few clarifications - 1. to make sure, this is desktop Outlook and if so could you include Outlook and Windows version? 2. Could you describe a bit more about the addin - is your addin a taskpane or ExecuteFunction? If it's ExecuteFunction What API are you using to launch your app? 3. When you say crashes - do you mean the addin closes? Screenshots or a video would also help us understand the scenario better.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but: 15003 - **ERROR_EVT_EVENT_TEMPLATE_NOT_FOUND**  - "_The template for an event definition cannot be found in the resource_".

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Here is a screen recording https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SxonktpVyFKS_QL6R-NeBiw-v9d_B0be/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: Answering other questions - 1. Outlook Version Build 13029.20308, Windows Build 18363.959. 2. The Add Template command in the video is via a ExecuteFunction, and we use the Dialog API to open the templates. 3. Usually it's only the Desktop App Web Viewer that houses the Templates view crashes. But rarely, Outlook will crash as in the video.

Please let me know if you have additional questions. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for sharing the video. What API are you using to add the attachment? Do you add the attachment directly to the OutlookItem or to the template in the browser page that opens up in displayDialog? Do you see any console errors associated when attaching the attachment?

Comment: We're uploading attachments to the template in the browser page via a regular form input element. I can't see logs because it only happens in Windows Outlook.

Comment: I am trying to follow up with people who may be more familiar with this. But in the meantime, when the crash happens can you check the Windows Event Viewer, and filter on Errors, and see if there are any faulting applications at that time? (it will likely be Outlook.exe, or msoadfsb.exe). If you have that log can you add that to your recent post? (namely we are looking for the Report Id:

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, there aren't any useful logs around the time of the crash. The only Outlook log that I see says "Reconciliation completed for the following store..." and there is one more Informational log that says "The Software Protection service has stopped."

Comment: I'm also facing this issue, when I open outlook compose mail and open web add-in taskpane and then I upload file very first time web add-in getting crashed and restarted. After that if I select different file to upload it doesn't crash. I'm using outlook Version 2007(Build 13029.20460)

Comment: Add-in Error
Sorry, we had to restart because this add-in wasn't responding.
P1: Apps for Office
P2: 16.0.13029.20342
P3: 0x80043074
P4: 
This is event Error

Answer (score 1):

We have fixed the bug and the fix should be available in build 16.0.13603.10000 or later. When an updated build is available depends on the release channel a customer is on.