# Outlook web add-in crashes frequently while uploading file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, outlook, outlook-web-addins

I am working on Outlook Web Add-in developing using ReactJs, I have compose task-pane Add-In where I'm using this file uploader. So whenever I tried to upload any file of any size (small or large) the taskpane crashes and restarting Add-In. And mostly it happens uploading first time any file. Am I doing something wrong in code or is it any Outlook issue?

I aslo tried some react npm package for dropzone which also getting this same error. I have attached screenshot of error, Event of outlook alert and code of my file uploader.

---

Windows 10 Home (19041.388)
Outlook Version 2007(Build 13029.20344 Click-to-Run)

[image: AddIn Error]

[image: Event Viewer Error Report]

```ts
import * as React from "react";
import { MessageBar } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/MessageBar";

interface DocumentUploaderProps {
    handleOnDropFiles: (files: any, callback?: any) => void;
}

export default class DocumentUploader extends React.Component<DocumentUploaderProps> {
    inputFileRef;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.inputFileRef = React.createRef();
    }
    dragOver = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    dragEnter = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    dragLeave = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    fileDrop = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const files = e.dataTransfer.files;
        this.props.handleOnDropFiles(files, () => this.inputFileRef.current.value = "");
    }
    onClickDropzone = () => {
        this.inputFileRef.current.click();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ms-Grid-row">
                <div className="ms-Grid-col ms-sm12">
                    <div className="dz-container">
                        <section
                            className="dropzone"
                            onDragOver={this.dragOver}
                            onDragEnter={this.dragEnter}
                            onDragLeave={this.dragLeave}
                            onDrop={this.fileDrop}
                            onClick={this.onClickDropzone}
                        >
                            <div>
                                <input
                                    ref={this.inputFileRef}
                                    type="file"
                                    style={{ display: "none" }}
                                    onChange={(e) => this.props.handleOnDropFiles(e.target.files, () => this.inputFileRef.current.value = "")}
                                    multiple
                                />
                                <p className="upload-icon">
                                    <i className="fas fa-file-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </p>
                                <p className="ms-fontWeight-bold dropzone-msg">Click or drag files here</p>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Try replacing this.inputFileRef everywhere to this.inputFileRef.current

Comment: I tried replacing `this.inputFileRef.current` but still its crashing, but when I use simple native input type=file **without** dropzone div and not hiding file input and mimicking file input click event to dropzone div click than it never crash

Comment: Can you the update the code above with latest one that you tried

Comment: For now i have used `<input type=file />` and it is hidden using `visible:0` CSS and fixed overlapped upon dropzone div. So i have fixed like this.

Comment: We are unable to reproduce this issue. on our end. A good thing would be to check whether you hit this issue with Vanilla JavaScript (no React JS). If yes, we would you like to get a full but simple repro script. You could leverage ScriptLab add-in from store to build the repro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were able to reproduce this issue in-house using data from this post and [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63306471/uploading-a-file-crashes-desktop-app-web-viewer/65137648#65137648). We have fixed the bug and the fix should be available in build 16.0.13603.10000 or later. When an updated build is available depends on the release channel a customer is on.